# Why Does DreamWeaver CS5 Discriminate between File Extensions, Even After Modding Mime Types?

Tags: php, dreamweaver, file-extension, mime-types, adobe-cs5

[image: .php file extension in DreamWeaver CS5]
[image: .ast file extension in DreamWeaver CS5]

Hi folks, Even After I forced DreamWeaver CS5 to allow opening of .ast extensions as a MIME type of php5, which DreamWeaver now opens and colors correctly [as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/115614/how-make-dreamweaver-color-the-code-as-php-for-inc-files), I still have trouble figuring out why it still discriminates between the two file extensions!

**Symptoms: External Files & Design View**
I have a file foo.php which php includes other files (e.g. the php-combined css.php and js.php). Now, when opening foo.php all functions work perfectly: the external (included) php files are all recognised correctly. However, when I change foo.php >> foo.ast, and open it again, It does not recognise the files extensions anymore in the top bar. Also, I lose the Design / Live View functionality.**

**When I change foo.ast to foo.php, all works again!

Anyone any clues of why there remains a a difference between one and other extension?**

**Note1:** I have added the `.ast` extension to these four files, next to `.php`:
**1** C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\DocumentTypes\MMDocumentTypes.xml
**2** C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\DocumentTypes\MMDocumentTypes.xml
**3** C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS5\en_US\Configuration\Extensions.txt
**4** C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\Extensions.txt

**Note2:** sometimes, even .php files do not want to show in design view or live view. Could this be caused by a corrupted installation?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, although with a different file type.

Do you have a MMDocumentTypes.xml file in C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS5\en_US\Configuration\DocumentTypes?  If so, I would add the .ast extension to it.

Comment: thanks Pete +1 you are my possible hero if solving this together. But wait: i see no `DocumentTypes` folder in my `/en_US/Configuration` root folder... are you sure you have that folder?